# This keeps popping up while I'm trying to get an animation working in Unity

Tags: unity

What does this mean? I've been trying to get a character to change animations when it is near an object. But nothing happens and this keeps showing up. Any advice? [image]

Comment: It would be much better it you posted this as a copy-paste of the text. We have a hard time reading what's on the picture.

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix this? The error description seems quite relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is as warning says you disabled exit time but didn't set any parameter for transition. To get rid of the warning you need to do one of these things.
So if you want to do animation transition when something happens you need to create a parameter in animator and set it on the transition. Then when something happens you can change the value of parameter in code to whatever you set it for that transition. You can find a lot of tutorial on doing animation transition or just take a look at documentation.